# Check if data validation passed

Tags: vba, excel, validation

Is there any way in VBA to check if a cells' value meets the data validation criteria for that cell? e.g. in pseudo code: `Cell.Validation.isValid`

The situation is that:

- The validation criteria is a list of values in a **named range**
- I **do** want the user to be able to enter something that isn't in the validation list
- The validation lists are dynamically built (I could just go and check the data that was used to build the lists but hey,
  the validation formula already contains the data so I'm interested to know if it can be used without recycling code)
- I want to check this after the user has entered the data, not while they are doing it

Comment: This question is *too broad*. There are many ways to check data like this and without some code you have tried/ something which isn't working we won't be able to give you specific responses. If you are *just wondering* something, this is probably not the place to ask. If you have a specific question which is a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then we can answer it.

Comment: Without seeing a more specific example we can't provide a very effective method of accomplishing this. My best recommendation though would be to consider checking the entered value against an array of values by loading your named range into an array and then looping through it. While not the most efficient method, it should still be able to run in a matter of seconds (if not microseconds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is probably full of holes, but I found this worked for me.

[image]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rRange As Range

    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        If Not (IsEmpty(Target.Validation.Formula1)) Then
            Set rRange = ThisWorkbook.Names(Replace(Target.Validation.Formula1, "=", "")).RefersToRange
            MsgBox "Is In Range:=" & Not rRange.Find(Target.Value, rRange.Cells(1), xlValues, xlWhole) Is Nothing
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the Validation.Value property

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.validation.value